# Automatic imports from multiple implicit objects

Tags: scala, typeclass

I just found the type class concept of Scala and like it actually very much. The problem I have it that all examples I found put the type classes (objects) under one object (Like here: http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html)

Maybe this is wrong but I am a friend of having one file per class. So what I like to do is to put the type classes into several files which would mean that each implementation needs to be put into a seperate object. This now leads to the "problem" that I need to import every single implementation manually. To clarify better here a small example:

```
package sth

import sth.like.Like
import sth.like.StringLike._
import sth.like.IntLike._

object Application extends App {
    def t[T](arg: T)(implicit l: Like[T]) = {
        l.print(arg)
    }

    t(1)
    t("Blub")
}
```

-

```
package sth.like

trait Like[T] {
    def print(arg: T)
}
```

-

```
package sth.like

object IntLike {
    implicit object LikeIntLike extends Like[Int] {
        def print(arg: Int): Unit = println(s"INT $arg")
    }
}
```

-

```
package sth.like

object StringLike {
    implicit object LikeStringLike extends Like[String] {
        override def print(arg: String): Unit = println(s"STRING: $arg")
    }
}
```

This works so far. I know, the wildcard import in Application is not necessary but that is not the point. As you can see I need to import both StringLike and IntLike in Application because otherwise these are not available for the Application object.

So is it possible to do this in a generic way or is it completely bad practise to do it this way?

Answer (score 6):

You could put your implicits inside traits, not objects

```
trait IntLike {
  implicit object LikeIntLike extends Like[Int] {
    def print(arg: Int): Unit = println(s"INT $arg")
  }
}
```

And then have object with the same name, extending this trait, which would give you what you had earlier, you can import each implicit individually.

```
object IntLike extends IntLike
```

You can do the same for all other instances of your typeclass:

```
trait StringLike {
  implicit object LikeStringLike extends Like[String] {
    override def print(arg: String): Unit = println(s"STRING: $arg")
  }
}

object StringLike extends StringLike
```

And in another file, you can combine all traits together like this:

```
object Implicits extends StringLike with IntLike
```

and import just the `Implicits` object if you want all your implicits in scope.

```
package sth

import sth.like.Like
import sth.like.Implicits._

object Application extends App {
  def t[T](arg: T)(implicit l: Like[T]) = {
    l.print(arg)
  }

  t(1)
  t("Blub")
}
```

Optionally, you can mixin traits you need

```
object Application extends App with StringLike with IntLike { ... }
```

or even do

```
trait Implicits extends StringLike with IntLike
object Implicits extends Implicits

object Application extends App with Implicits { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for your answer. But I also would need to add new type classes manually to the Implicits, wouldn't I?

Couldn't I use then package objects for simplicity reasons like here:

http://naildrivin5.com/scalatour/wiki_pages/PackageObjects/

?

I mean this part:

```
package opower {
   package object controller {
       type Secured = org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured
       type Controller = org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
       ...
   }
}
```

Since it seems that there is no dynamic way I could just put all type classes into the controller object and could this then import.

Or do I missunderstand the package object?